# Is there a regex to find text between two tags?

Tags: regex

I have a text which contains some xml and i'm trying to match each group.

```
<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>Some text 
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>page.htm
<DESCRIPTION>some text
<TEXT>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</DOCUMENT>

<DOCUMENT>
<TYPE>Some text 2
<SEQUENCE>1
<FILENAME>page2.htm
<DESCRIPTION>some text 2
<TEXT>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
</DOCUMENT>
```

I tried to get each group of `<DOCUMENT> ... </DOCUMENT>`, but i keep getting the whole text not each group.
I have tried with `(<DOCUMENT>)([^&]*)(<\DOCUMENT>)` and a few others, but couldn't get it in groups.

Comment: `some xml and i'm trying to match each group` What do you mean by _each group_ ?

Comment: For starters your xml is not valid? And why use regex when there are tools for xml parsing?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the form `/start(.*?)end/` will work for PCRE non-greedy matching of text between start and end delimiters. You may need to turn on the multi-line flag if your text contains newlines. The `?` is the ticket - it turns the match from a greedy (matching from the start token to the last end token) to non-greedy (matching from the start token to the first instance of the end token).

That said, if this is actually a markup document, remember the golden rule: [don't parse XML with regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/271475).